# Graphql authentication on Power BI Services

Tags: graphql, powerbi-datasource

I have a Power BI dataset with Graphql connection already developed in PBI Desktop, and now I needs to publish to Power BI services and setup schedule refresh. I'm stuck at the step to set up credentials. Does anyone have experience or know how to set up the Data Source Credentials? Thanks heaps.

[image: configuration screen]

I have pretty much tried all the options in this configuration step, however none of them successful.